# Running a command based on output of previous command

Tags: bash

Consider the following command. I want to echo "yes" if grep has output and echo "no" if grep returns no output.

`cat myfile | grep "something"`

Can I do this without `if` command?

Comment: Aside from the useless use of `cat`, what exactly is your problem with `if`?  Or maybe the correct question is "what are you *really* trying to do?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [boolean control operators](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals?highlight=%28&&%29#Control_Operators_.28.26.26_and_.7C.7C.29):

```
[[ -n $(your command) ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Answer (score 5):

`grep` sets its exit code to 0 ("success") if it finds something:

```
grep something myfile &>/dev/null && echo yes || echo no
```

Comment: You can also use `grep -q` then you don't need `&>/dev/null`.